# The partial name (sets/3/0) is not a valid Ruby identifier

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partials

I am trying to render a decently-complex series of partials in my app and am getting the following error message:

```
The partial name (sets/3/1) is not a valid Ruby identifier; make sure your partial name starts with underscore, and is followed by any combination of letters, numbers and underscores.
```

This partial is rendered from my `generators#show` action, using the following code:

```
<% @random_partial = 'sets/' + bucket.to_s + '/' + rand(2).round.to_s %>
<%= render partial: @random_partial %>
```

`bucket` is a number (between 1 and 7, not that that matters) and the random number is to choose a random partial from anything in that `bucket`.  The file structure currently looks like this:

```
generators
|--exercises
    |--_cardio0.html.erb
    |--_cardio1.html.erb
    |--_weight0.html.erb
    |--_weight1.html.erb
|--sets
    |--1
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
    |--2
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
    |--3
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
    |--4
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
    |--5
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
    |--6
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
    |--7
       |--_0.html.erb
       |--_1.html.erb
|--new.html.erb
|--show.html.erb
```

Finally, I don't think this impacts the error being displayed, but this is a sample of what one of the `sets` partials looks like:

```
<% @random_cardio_1 = 'exercises/_cardio' + rand(2).round.to_s %>
Five Minutes of <%= render partial: @random_cardio_1 %>

<% @random_cardio_2 = 'exercises/_cardio' + rand(2).round.to_s %>
Five Minutes of <%= render partial: @random_cardio_2 %>

<% @random_cardio_3 = 'exercises/_cardio' + rand(2).round.to_s %>
Five Minutes of <%= render partial: @random_cardio_3 %>
```

Can anyone else figure out why this error is being generated or how to correct this code?

Comment: what version is your rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested and found out that we can't have a partial with integer as a name as yours in Rails 4. There are some problems in your code.

First, we refer the partial using relative directory after `app/views`. So add `generators/` at the start of the path.

Second, as I mentioned earlier that you can't use an integer as partial name, please rename your partial into something else. For example I will add `p` to your integer named partials. So `_1.html.erb` will be renamed to `_p1.html.erb`.

Third, do not add additional `_` when referring to your partial. This `'generators/sets/' + bucket.to_s + '/' + rand(2).round.to_s` is OK, but this `<% @random_cardio_3 = 'exercises/_cardio' + rand(2).round.to_s %>` is not OK.

So you can render it by,

```
<% @random_partial = 'generators/sets/' + bucket.to_s + '/p' + rand(2).round.to_s %>
<%= render partial: @random_partial %>
```

and for the nested partial remove `_` before `cardio`

```
<% @random_cardio_3 = 'generators/exercises/cardio' + rand(2).round.to_s %>
Five Minutes of <%= render partial: @random_cardio_3 %>
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is really great information to have and it worked perfectly.